# Airflow Adaptive Server connection failed

Tags: sql, sql-server, airflow

I want to connect my Airflow and Microsoft SQL Server. I configured my connection under 'connections' bar in 'Admin' box as mentioned in the following link:
http://airflow.apache.org/howto/manage-connections.html

But when I run my Dag task that is related to SQL server immedatly fails by following error:

```
[2019-03-28 16:16:07,439] {models.py:1788} ERROR - (18456, "Login failed for user 'XXXX'.DB-Lib error message 20018, severity 14:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\nDB-Lib error message 20002, severity 9:\nAdaptive Server connection failed (***.***.***.28:1433)\n")
```

My code from DAG for Micrososft Sql Connection is following:

```
sql_command = """
select * from [sys].[tables]
"""
t3 = MsSqlOperator( task_id = 'run_test_proc',

                    mssql_conn_id = 'FIConnection',

                    sql = sql_command,

                    dag = dag)
```

I verified ip address and port number kind of configuration things by establishing connection through pymssql library from my local computer. Test code is following:

```
pymssql.connect(server="***.***.***.28:1433",
                    user="XXXX",
                    password="XXXXXX"
                    ) as conn:
                    df = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM [sys].[tables]", conn)
                    print(df)
```

Could you please share if you have experienced this issue?

By the way I am using VirtualBox in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: Sounds like you need to check the username/password combo.

Comment: I tried with same user name and password combo in my pymssql test it worked. I changed it to xxxx for security reasons :)

Comment: Well of course you wouldn't post the real values here. The point is the error message is telling you that the user can't connect with the credentials provided. Does the user exist? Have you double checked the username and password?

Comment: sorry for misunderstanding. Yes I checked lots of times username and password as I say above I checked logging in with same values on my python script.

Comment: In the Airflow Connection UI, try setting the `Host` to the SQL Server Name, rather than `<ip address>:<port>` (run `SELECT @@SERVERNAME;`). 

Also, are there any special characters in the password that need to be escaped?

Comment: The error was happening because of one missing charachter in db name. Thanks for your help

Comment: Hello Nihad,  Can you post your fix?  where is the db name specified above?  Thanks in advance.  Bharat

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem because freetds-dev was missing on linux:

`apt-get install freetds-dev`